# Problem displaying and hiding a Spinner on AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, css, spinner

I am creating a form which works fine and posting the results to the backend using AJAX. To enhance User Experience, I have added a spinner which should display when a user triggers an event of clicking a button in the form and immediately removes the spinner when once there is success in the AJAX request,, I am trying to add or remove a dynamic class using CSS which aint working

**Layout**

```
<div class="container PAY">
     <div class="card-deck payment">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top payment" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/mpesa.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title payment"><a href="#" id="mpesa" class="mpesa">Make Payment</a></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="modal" id="modal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    margin-top: 10%;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     400px;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('../images/ajax-loader-2.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

/*Make sure the modal class is hidden by default and we control the style using Js*/
.PAY.loading .modal {
    display:none;   
}
```

**AJAX call to either add or remove a button**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Trigger button
$('.mpesa').on('click', function () {
    //Adds Class to the page when it loads
    ajaxStart: function() { #PAY.addClass("loading");    },
    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
            console.log(response);
             //Removes class when the page loads
            ajaxStart: function() { #PAY.removeClass("loading");}
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: `#PAY` is invalid JavaScript. Did you mean `$('.PAY')`? (Also, that `ajaxStart: ...` is in a very weird shape and/or place...)

Comment: @Amadan Yah sure I was to get the element by the class  , have rectified it but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're using global `ajaxStart`/`ajaxStop` handlers, or you're turning things on/off on a per-request basis.

Here's the per-request one (probably, as I didn't test it for additional errors):

```
$('.mpesa').on('click', function () {
    //Adds Class to the page when it loads
    $('.PAY').addClass("loading");

    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
            console.log(response);

             //Removes class when the page loads
            $('.PAY').removeClass("loading");
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This has a chance to do the wrong thing when several requests happen to overlap, so this is better:

```
// Do this once only, then forget about it
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function() { $('.PAY').addClass("loading"); })
  .ajaxStop(function() { $('.PAY').removeClass("loading"); })
```

and then later in code never mention `.PAY`, `loading` or `ajaxStart` ever again.

Comment: ,, Well thanks it works fine,,, I did not undersatnd the 2nd code block,, Did  you mean I add it at the top of my Jquery code

Comment: At the top of your code code. Start of script. Not sure what you mean by “my jQuery code”.

Comment: ,, I understood you,, thanks alot,, The spinner works well.. Is it possible to  stop it when the user clicks on any part of the page before the AJAX request completes

Comment: Sure. Handle click event and remove the loading class.